# Getting error when trying to log into admin page using django

Tags: django

I am trying to log into the admin page on django. I have a superuser account but when I try to login I get this error:  ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I got the same error because of simple mistake as a beginner. Instead of running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I typed

```
python manage.py migrate
```

So the table was not created then and the error meant just that it couldn't find the table where to insert the values.

On the other hand, if above will not help after manage.py makemigrations, you can try

```
python manage.py migrate --fake appname
```

(where appname is your application`s name) and after do one more time

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and it should work.